# Sidekiq fetches inconsistent data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sidekiq

```
class A
  ....
  def something
    if condition
      mark_completed
      // here I can see the object progress is completed
      CompletionStatsWorker.perform_async(self.id)
    end
  end

  def mark_completed
    self.update_attributes!(progress: 'completed')  
  end
end
```

In the worker:

```
class CompletionStatsWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    obj = A.find(id)
    //here I'm getting the progress of the same object as 'progressing'
  end
end
```

Sidekiq somehow fetches old data even if it is triggered after the successful field updation. I can see that the object `updated_at` is not same as the actual `updated_at` value. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may happens because `sidekiq` works faster than it commited to DB, you should add `CompletionStatsWorker.perform_async(self.id)` to `after_commit` callback or change method to :

```
  def something
    if condition
      if mark_completed
        // here I can see the object progress is completed
        CompletionStatsWorker.perform_async(self.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

take a look [sidekiq docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-find-modelname-with-id12345)

Comment: Hey Oleg, I've tried both. The strange thing is that, the progress is completed before I'm calling the worker. But inside the worker, it again shows the status as progressing. But in db, it is completed itself.

Comment: you can try, just for checking, after `mark_completed` method add `sleep 1`. Is it same in this case?